# Cyrillic encoding problem in a bad style template

Tags: packages, input-encodings, cyrillic

I have encountered curious problem. I am playing with a paper manuscript. The journal has its own style for submission, say, `bad_template.sty` which I am trying for the template manuscript (both the `.sty` file and template manuscript are provided by the journal, but the manuscript refuses to compile!!! - laughable). 
Its mainly about minutiae of article formatting, however, it allows for two languages (Russian and English) – at least, in theory. Part which concerns me is this:

```
\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\RequirePackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[english,russian]{babel}
```

When I am trying to compile the document:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{bad_template}
\begin{document}
Some text in Cyrillic - Текст кириллицей
\end{document}
```

So, when I compile with pdflatex, I get something unintelligible – **їЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ**
When I try an obvious fix – to change `[cp1251]` to `[utf8]{inputenc}` – the system gives me a lot of errors (like this) - **: Unicode char � (U+FFFD)** – and the document doesn’t compile. 
The style file is very sloppy, I am wondering if there is an easy fix, except going line by line and essentially recreating the style file? Thank you!

Comment: If the journal requires files to be encoded in `cp1251` they won't be happy about your `utf8` submission. Ask the editors for advice.

Comment: If you submit the TeX sources to the journal any changes you do to your local `bad_template` will either be irrelevant because the journal uses their version of `bad_template` without the changes or could cause a huge mess if you send incompatible changes. I guess the best course of action is to contact the editor with a small example of what does not work and ask for advice.